# Поиск и операции над словом в потоке ввода, варианты и критика решения

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы, предикат, поток-ввода

Хочу сделать поэлегантнее поиск символьной комбинации в стандартном потоке ввода, не через циклы `while`, а с использованием предиката и алгоритма `std::find_if`. Дошел до такого решения:

```
std::find_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             Predicate());
```

где `Predicate()` вызов конструктора класса `Predicate` с определенным оператором `()`.

Есть какие-нибудь еще подходы к решению данной задачи? Может с использованием других алгоритмов STL или на основе возможностей новых стандартов, о которых я еще не слышал (замена предиката на лямбду не в счет)?

Comment: Наверное, `istream_iterator`, но не суть... Беда в том, что так вы работаете *с одним символом*. Так что в лучшем случае ваш предикат должен хранить предыдущие символы, чтобы понять, нашел ли он то, что нужно, или еще нет...

Comment: @Harry Да, итератор исправил. Так в нем же стоит <string>, разве он не по словам будет забирать из входного потока элементы?

Comment: А, пардон, не обратил внимания... Ну, если поиск в пределах слова, то нет вопросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ищется комбинация из 2-х символов, то хорошо подойдет `adjacent_find` с предикатом на 2 нужных символа. Иначе используем `find_if` и предикат с внутренним состоянием.